# Firebase, autentificacion con telefono y google

Tags: android, firebase, autenticación

En mi aplicación uso Firebase para autenticarme.

Primero el usuario se autentica con el teléfono, necesito verificarlo y luego en el momento quiera, puede loguearse con Google para tener una mejor experiencia sobre la app.

El login en ambos lo hace perfecto, no tengo ningún problema con eso, es más, desinstalas la app, vuelves a instalarla y es como si nada hubiera pasado.

Pero el problema que tengo es que cuando el usuario cambia su número de teléfono y vuelve a entrar a la aplicación (ej. La desinstalo y volvió a instalar) se registra con su número, luego si quiere usar su cuenta de Google, me da este error:

**SIGN_IN**

> com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException: This credential is already associated with a different user account.

**REAUTHENTICATE**

> com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The supplied credentials do not correspond to the previously signed in user.

Que es lo que puedo hacer para que el usuario pueda volver a usar su cuenta de Google con otro teléfono hasta ahora vengo borrando los usuarios viejos, pero no es bueno eso.

¿O qué otra alternativa tengo?

PD: por si dicen de activar múltiples cuentas por correo, no funciono.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, añade los errores como texto. Así nada más son difíciles de leer y estos en particular tiene un contraste pésimo.

Comment: @Alfabravo Actualize, gracias por avisar :D

Answer (score 0):

Firebase te permite crear una cuenta con distintas formas de autentificar como facebook, google, email, etc. Si creas una cuenta supongamos con email y contraseña y luego decides logearte con facebook tendras un problema de `FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException` esto se puede solucionar linkeando las cuentas con este metodo: `firebase.auth().currentUser.linkWithCredential(credential)`.

Pero antes que copies y peges hay un problema!. Para hacer el linkeo necesitas que exista un `currentUser`, y si no estas logeado no hay cuenta al cual puedas linkear  esta nueva forma de autentificacion y claro si estabas intentando logear entonces obvio no estas logeado.

Lo que debes hacer entonces es pedirle al usuario que se autentifique con el metodo que uso anteriormente, esto lo podes saber usando metodo `firebase.auth().fetchProvidersForEmail(email)` que te traera una lista con los metodos de autentificacion validos para esa cuenta.

Finalmente ahora que ya estas autentificado correctamente podes usar el metodo de `linkWithCredential()` usando la credencial que habia dado CollisionException para permitir que la proxima vez tu usario pueda autentificarse con ese metodo y no vuelvas a tener el CollisionException.

Comment: Gracias por responser!, entiendo bien lo que decis, pero no estoy seguro que con eso estaria resolviendo el problema.
Hagamos un ejemplo.
Yo por primera vez que me registre a la app me registre con el numero de telefono 1234, posteriormente, asocie mi cuenta de google LcsGrz a ese numero.

Por razones decido desistalar la app, y cambiar mi numero.

Al volver a bajarla me registro con mi nuevo numer '4321', pero al momento de linkear mi cuenta de google, me dice que esta asociada a otro usuario que no es el mio.

Ahi, en ese caso, que debo hacer?

Comment: Que problema! Esta bien que firebase diga que son cuentas distintas, porque lo son, en este caso lo que queres hacer no es un linkeo de cuentas, sino mergear ambas cuentas una sola, hasta donde yo conozco firebase eso no se puede hacer. Lo correcto hubiera sido logear con google, y vincular el nuevo telefono a esa cuenta (habria que manejar el error tambien para poder desvincular el telefono viejo). Despues contame si le encontras una solucion.